# Сайт не отдает заголовков и возвращает пустой результат на любой запрос

Tags: php, парсер, curl

Возникла проблема: внезапно сайт поставщика, с которого я собираю остатки начал отдавать пустой результат. file_get_contents возвращает пустоту. На код ниже в ответ false. Думала меня по ip забанили, но сделала запрос через прокси, а результат такой же. Помогите, пожалуйста, понять в чем сложность?

```
$url='http://svetlana.msk.ru/';
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
var_dump(curl_exec($ch));
```

Comment: Домен, указанный в переменной `$url`, не ресолвится. Другими словами, нет больше такого сайта.

Comment: Хм, это случилось ровно сейчас после публикации вопроса. Еще 20 минут назад работал и Яндекс Вебмастер отдавал загаловки данного сайта. Подожду, может, сайт сейчас куда-то переносят.